# phpThumb cache problems

Tags: php, thumbnails, phpthumb

I'm using phpThumb - the PHP thumbnail generator.

'phpThumb.config.php':

```
$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['cache_maxage'] = 10; 

$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['cache_maxsize'] = 1000; 

$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['cache_maxfiles'] = 10;
```

but it does nothing... I've got 108 MB in 922 files... and it keeps growing.

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was really simple. After installing phpthumb with the default settings the line `$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['document_root'] = realpath((getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT') && ereg('^'.preg_quote(realpath(getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT'))), realpath(__FILE__))) ? getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT') : str_replace(dirname(@$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/', dirname(__FILE__))));` wasn't uncommeted and all seems to work fine.

**BUT:** the **/tmp directory** runs **out of space** in very short time on a high frequented page.

**SOLUTION:** It was simple, since phpthumb needs WRITE PERMISSIONS on its $PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['cache_directory'] directory. So be sure that the user who executes your php scripts (usually apache) has the permission to write, otherwise the /tmp directory will be used and filled up with your cached files.

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'd check that the user that php is running as has write permissions on the cache folder.

Have you checked the php error log?

Answer (score 0):

funny, in *phpThumb.config.php* default line was uncommented:

```
$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['document_root'] = realpath((getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT') && ereg('^'.preg_quote(realpath(getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT'))), realpath(__FILE__))) ? getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT') : str_replace(dirname(@$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/', dirname(__FILE__))));
```

..and phpThumb succeed in saving files into 'cache' dir, but was unable to delete any files.

I setted $PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['document_root'] mannualy and it works!

So, doublecheck if $PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['document_root'] is correct.

Answer (score -2):

it's simple, you just delete the cache folder.
phpThumb will re-create your thumb later.